# Android webView zoom out

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to show the google developer console in a webview. The problem is that the minimal zoom is really large.

With this code I can zoom in the site wery well, but not zoom out.

The

```
    webView.setInitialScale(50);
```

string allows to display zoomed out page on loading, but once i pinch to zoom the web page scales to large page and i cant zoom out again.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.setInitialScale(50);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    setContentView(webView);

    final Activity activity = this;
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("https://play.google.com/apps/publish/");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you find the answer? I meet this problem also. Use this may help you. But I need to set the initial scale.

```
             webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
             webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```